# Pixel Art Square

Tags: python, unicode, ascii, pixel

I am creating a pixel art of a 64x64 Pixel image on my terminal using Python. The Problem is that it is ASCII and because of that the image always comes out as a rectangle and not as a square as you can see on the image. (I have checked and the characters are really 64x64)

[image: see here]

My Question is: Is there a known/best practice way to deal with that or are there other ways like using Unicode instead of ASCII or get a perfectly square character to print the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so i literally just found a workaround.   
It's really simple, instead of using one `#` as a pixel I just use two `##`.

It looks a lot better
[image]

Comment: Sadly cant mark this as an answer yet but i will be back

Comment: that - or you can use the half-block characters, {' ', '▀', '▄', '█'}  - though you have to carefully manipulate foreground and background for it to work.
The "terminedia" project is capable of doing so. 
https://github.com/jsbueno/terminedia